# Blender 2.8 Cycles Projecting world background to an object

Tags: camera, world, hdri

How can i project world environment hdri texture to an object,like camera mapping, i know i can use a material that has only shadows for later compositing it,and rendering the world environment alone, but i'd like to know if there is a way to do that, a kind of background shader? or using nodes and vectors/rays in shader editor? Thanks

Comment: I must be misunderstanding--surely you know how to map any texture to any object? Is that what you want, or is the background itself not visible in the render like it used to be? Is your environmental texture only showing in reflections, and you want to act like a "skybox" again?

Comment: Yes i know how to map any texture to any object, in this case i'm not able to give a world background shader to an object, projected from view, to let it results like hidden or invisible as having same colors of world environment background behind it.Maybe background shader was doing that but i've read somewhere they left it from 2.8 version.